# Path to TFLite in mlkit with android studio

Tags: android, google-mlkit

In Vision Quickstart in MLKit, I am going to replace /custom_models/object_labeler.tflite with my TFLite file. I tried to find "path" in codes that binds tflite file but failed. I tried the following but failed to bind my_tflite.tflite.

```
companion object {
    private const val TAG ="ObjectDetectorProcessor"
    private const val CUSTOM_MODEL_PATH = "custom_models/my_tflite.tflite"
}
```

How can I bind my tflite file?

Comment: Model is hooked up here https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/master/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/java/LivePreviewActivity.java#L195

Answer (score 0):

I tried myself with the test. When I downloaded TFLite, the Project/app looks like the following.
[image]

Then replace custom_models/object_labeler.tflite with the file in ml folder, with renaming it as "object_labeler.tflite". This affects only "Custom Object Detection".